# How to enable X-XSS protection header from webpage in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xss

I want to enable a header property named "X-XSS-Protection" in my application.
This can be achieved by adding header i.e `<customHeaders>` from web.config file.

But for now I want to enable this property from web page itself.

I had tried following code.

```
Response.Headers.Add("X-XSS-Protection", "1");

HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers["X-XSS-Protection"] = "1";
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out this library: https://docs.nwebsec.com/en/4.2/nwebsec/NWebsec.Mvc.html
You can add security headers through MVC Attributes